# Review request for question marked as Duplicate

Tags: feature-request

There should have an option  to request for review in case the question is marked as duplicate but really not the duplicate .

Explanation : Suppose I asked a question and some one marked it as duplicate which is not a duplicate. In that case let some one review it and take a decesion.

Comment: Why? Marking as a duplicate is already a community moderation function needing 5 agreements to take effect. And closed questions can always be reopened with enough community support. I don't see why we would need another review function there. If you're talking about [this particular question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873606/jquery-flot-issue-in-chrome-stacks-are-not-filled-when-placeholder-div-width-is) then it only has 1 vote so far. Nothing is closed just yet.

Comment: In case there are less than 5 close votes the question will not be closed and people may pay less attention to that question

Comment: What logic is that based on? Got any proof to substantiate that claim? If anything, if it's not a duplicate, clearly state how it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Thats the human Psychology

Comment: Yeah, we're going to need a bit more than that to have developers spend time on a feature. And there is already a close-votes queue where users can vote to leave your question open. With enough such votes, the question will disappear from he queue and the existing vote will start to expire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct response is to edit your question to make it clear that it's not a duplicate.

That doesn't mean adding the line

> This is not a duplicate

It means adding more relevant information to the question to highlight the differences. It could be as little as:

> My question is about X while the other question is about Y

or

> I've tried the answers to the other question but they didn't work because of A, B and C.

Close votes expire, so if you are right and your question isn't a duplicate the existing votes will eventually disappear.

If your question does get closed then editing it will automatically add it to the [Reopen review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1533756) where the closure will be reviewed.